# Conjecture concerning sums of reciprocals of largest prime factors

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $x$ be an integer, $r(x)$ the reciprocal of the largest prime factor of $x$.

Let $f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} r(k) r(n-k)$  for which $k$ and $(n-k)$ are coprime.

For $n = 3 \dots 10$,  $f(n)  =  1\ \  0.6666\ \  1.3333\ \  0.4\ \  1.2\ \  0.419\ \  1.342\ \ 0.761$

For example:

$f(5) = r(1) r(4) + r(2) r(3) + r(3) r(2) + r(4) r(1) = 1/2 + 1/2\ \ 1/3 + 1/3\ \ 1/2 + 1/2 = 1.3333$

Put $s(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}$ f(k)

> **Conjecture.**
>   $s(n)/n$  tends to a number $p$,  where $0<p<1$ as $n\to\infty$.

$s(1000) = 0.7913$ x 1000

Comment: I plotted the first 10000 values of $\frac{s(n)}n$ using Sage and it seems not to converge, see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4itvx.png). By the way, I got $s(1000)\approx0.79095\times1000$. It should be noted that my code calculates $\frac{s(n)}n$ recursively as $\frac{s(n)}n=\frac{(n-1)\cdot \frac{s(n-1)}{n-1}+f(n)}n$ so I may be blowing up rounding errors, I'm not sure.

Comment: Computer-aided evaluations up to $n=10^4$ confirm @barto's suspicions.

Comment: Oh dear! Thanks for your help. Seems I am being proved wrong. Am pressing on beyond 1000. Our numbers for s(1000) nearly agree.